# How to stay informed of disease outbreaks

Tags: health, international-travel

How can a traveler be informed of any communicable disease outbreaks in the region one is traveling to? (or the city one is in). Is there an app/radio station that keeps a track of these outbreaks? Does an international CDC (Centre for Disease Control)  exist, which keeps a track of outbreaks across the world?

Comment: That would be the WHO but information for travelers is probably not their highest priority.

Answer (score 6):

There are several!

The CDC actually monitors worldwide as well as other groups (World Health Organisation, for example).

The WHO has a [GAR (Global Alert and Response) page](http://www.who.int/csr/don/en/) which coverts, alerts, outbreaks and news on diseases in countries worldwide.

If you want something less...dry, you may like the [Global Incident Map of outbreaks](http://outbreaks.globalincidentmap.com/home.php).  It's one of the easiest to tell at a glance if there's something in your region of choice.

[Healthmap](http://healthmap.org/en/) is similar, but not as detailed.

And of course you should always just keep an eye on your own country's travel alerts.  For example, Australia has their [Travel Advisory Alerts page](http://www.smartraveller.gov.au/zw-cgi/view/Advice/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your profile that you're in the USA (on a global site, it's really not very helpful to just say "Location: Bham").  In that case, the State Department has a page of [Travel Warnings and Alerts](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/alertswarnings.html).  Warnings are for long-term problems; Alerts for typically short-term issues, including disease outbreaks.

Comment: Location is mostly irrelevant for reading travel warnings from various international agencies and noone said that even if it is populated it's actually true.

Comment: @Karlson If what is populated?

Comment: The location field in the bio.

Comment: @Karlson My reasoning was that, if he lives in the US, he probably has a feeling for how reliable information from the US State Department is likely to be. It's harder to know how much to trust information from an organization you've never heard of or not had much interaction with.

Comment: I understand the reasoning, however, there are organizations with world reach including the US State Department, UK Foreign & Commonwealth Office, Australian Foreign Affairs, CDC, WHO, and so on.  My Point wasn't about them but the reliance on the Free Form field called "Location" in the BIO, on determining the location.  It could instead of Bham say Home.  If the information is relevant and source is generally reliable or official location of the asker isn't important.